# MySQL .idb grows rapidly

Tags: mysql, database, jpa, eclipselink

I have a database which contains a log. Every log is active for a different amount of time, and in the active time it is continuously added to.

It's a very simple table, and a SHOW CREATE TABLE shows:

```
'TESTLOG', 'CREATE TABLE `TESTLOG` (
`Data` longtext NOT NULL,
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=672 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

All the data in the table is currently 6.52  Mb, which is great. But the server is rapidly loosing free space, and I traced the location to /var/lib/mysql/*dbname*/ to the TESTLOG idb file.

See for example

```
[root@server bin]# du -sh /var/lib/mysql/dbname/* | grep TESTLOG
12K     /var/lib/mysql/dbname/TESTLOG.frm
1.2G    /var/lib/mysql/dbname/TESTLOG.ibd
```

For about 30 minutes ago I had to DROP the table and reload it, because it was taking all available space. At the moment the file grows approx 40-100 Mb/minute.

What can I do? The size of the data in the table itself isn't rising as fast. Over the last 10-15 minutes it's gotten about 40kb bigger. I have no idea whats doing this and how to stop it - It wasn't like this yesterday, and I can't think of anything I've done that have had any relation to the testlog.

I really hope you can help - this sucks! :)

/Ben

Comment: you running transactions? perhaps that file's full of uncommitted transactions.

Comment: Yes - that could be right. Is there anyway I can check that?

Comment: `show engine innodb status` has all kinds of info in it. and check whatever's doing the log insertions. make sure autocommit is turned on.

Comment: I belive you were right mate. I had multiple threads writing to the testlogs, through a data access class. I protected everything from begin to commit with a mutex, and all seems better now. I belive you were right, that some internal locking stopped the system for committing. Please, Marc, post as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

As Marc B pointed out, the problem lied within uncomitted transactions. My belief is that multiple threads tried to update and read through multiple transactions, and somehow an internal locking took place. A mutex in the DAL layer fixed the problem :)